# android prompt user's input using a dialog

Tags: android

I would like to prompt the user to give me input in my android application using a dialog. this is what I have found:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
String value = input.getText();
 // Do something with value!
 }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
     // Canceled.
}
});

 alert.show();
```

but this 
gives me :

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

is there any problem on my code it seems like a null argument is passed on the dialog but I can't find out what is the problem.

Comment: `String value = input.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I ran your code in a new project, it worked fine. So probably "this" that you are using

- is not an activity
- is not the activity in view i.e. there might be a parent activity. If it is the child of some activity, use getParent() instead of "this".
- is null

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I've written a helper class that makes it easy to create a prompt dialog with only a few lines of code.

```
PromptDialog dlg = new PromptDialog(MainActivity.this, R.string.title, R.string.enter_comment) {
 @Override
 public boolean onOkClicked(String input) {
  // do something
  return true; // true = close dialog
 }
};
dlg.show();
```

**See full code =>** Prompt Dialog for Android

(The original link is not working http://www dot jjoe64 dot com/2011/06/prompt-dialog-for-android.html)