# Getting a user String in a dialog popup

Tags: android, android-layout

In my Android code, I inflate the GUI and store all the sub-elements in a different class. In that class, I want to add a method to read a user input from. I tried to follow something like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968170/Android-prompt-users-input-using-a-dialog) but no matter what I do, it boils down into copying a final value into a non final value. I though about creating another gui but couldn't fins a way to do so. Here is the method I have now:

```
private String setText(int id){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.show);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this.show);
        alert.setView(input);
        String out;
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Editable value = input.getText();
                out = value.toString();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Which I use to return a string into another method which set the value of the `TextView`.

---

I tried to do the following trick:

```
private String setText(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.show);
    final EditText input = new EditText(this.show);
    alert.setView(input);
    String out;
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            input.setText("canceled");
        }
    });
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


        }
    });
    alert.show();
    String toSend = input.getText().toString();
    this.maxT.setText(toSend);
    return toSend;
```

`maxT` is a `TextView` field. The app simply place an empty string. I figure that I should wait until the `AlertDialog` is closed, I'm searching for a way to do so.

Comment: you may want to send an intent containing the value you stored in "out" when the OK button is pressed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the id of your View and reference it:

```
private String setText(int id){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.show);
    EditText input = new EditText(this.show);
    input.setId("myInput");        
    alert.setView(input);
    String out;
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            EditText input = (EditText) dialog.findViewById("myInput");
            Editable value = input.getText();
            out = value.toString();               

        }
    });

}
```

}

View: [setId() API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29)

Dialogs onClick: [onClick() API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html#onClick%28android.content.DialogInterface,%20int%29)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I tried your solution but it didn't work. First, I can place a string in an ID only an int (I just put a number there) Second, I can use findViewById on Dialog for whatever reason. I don't know what I have messed up... I tried to bypass that but it didn't work (look at my edit for the question)

Comment: Got it. I have called another function. I read a little bit and found that android OS doesn't allow for GUI holding.

Comment: There is no `findViewbyId` on DialogInterface. It should be `getActivity().findViewById`

Comment: or cast the dialog to a dialog and use `findViewById`

Comment: Actually what @Blundell says is correct, you need to cast the DialogInterface because the EditText is added to the Dialog, not to the Activity.

Comment: As for now, the setId function requires IdRes integer. In other words, it should be declared at resource file and actual value will be generated at compile time. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36074347/1042836 shows how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom dialog and access the ID that way. If you want to use an alert dialog you can try this:

First create a layout with a single editText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText android:text="Stateful"
android:id="@+id/EditText01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then inflate this layout as in:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater= getLayoutInflater();
final View myView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
builder.setTitle("About");
builder.setMessage(alertMessage+"Version: "+versionName);
builder.setView(myView);
AlertDialog alert= builder.create();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea, I have implemented it in another way but it was useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Good post by Tony Stark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13268371/1114170) and you can beautify your dialog by adding an icon .. Make sure you have the picture in your drawable folder.

```
 builder.setTitle("Message Sent!").setCancelable(false).setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                            {public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {dialog.cancel();}});
                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.send);//call your image for your icon here
                            alert.show();
```

Example
[image]