# Alternative setButton

Tags: android

I use this code in my android project:

```
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
```

But, Eclipse says that `setButton()` is deprecated. Please, help me with an alternative solution. Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) for `setButton`? It tells you what method to use instead

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setTitle("ALERTTILESTRING")
        .setMessage("alertNameString")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

I hope the above code is a good one in which dialog works very well

Answer (score 34):

setButton() isn't what is deprecated, but that function + argument combination. There is still setButton(), but you need to give an ID for the button as the first argument for setButton():

```
alertDialog.setButton(0, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      <do something>;
    }
});
```

This is useful if you want to give all your buttons the same OnClickListener:

```
class alertDialogOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch(which){
            case 1:
                <do something>;
                break;
            case 2:
                <do something>;
                break;
        }
    }
}
alertDialog.setButton(1, "OK", new alertDialogOnClickListener());
alertDialog.setButton(2, "Cancel", new alertDialogOnClickListener());
```

Comment: This solution forces close: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Button does not exist

Comment: Instead of 0, 1 and so on use :DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE

DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE

DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL and so on

Answer (score 13):

Use: `setButton(int whichButton, CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener);`

For `whichButton` use one of the following:

```
DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE 
DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE
DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL
```

Answer (score 7):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Alert");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setMessage("Attention");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Get Location",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    });

            builder.setNeutralButton("Set Location",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {



                        }
                    });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Exit",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    });
            builder.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this and set positive or negative button

setButton(int whichButton, CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener);

refer this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setButton(int, java.lang.CharSequence, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my short and sweet one, an optimization of Android Developer. It's more concise and uses less memory.

```
    (new AlertDialog.Builder(/*activity*/))
    .setTitle("ALERTTILESTRING")
    .setMessage("alertNameString")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    })
    /*insert other Alert Dialog Builder methods here*/
    .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set three kind of buttons with alertDialog

```
.setPositiveButton("name_of_button",LISTENER);

.setNegativeButton("name_of_button",LISTENER);

.setNeutralButton("name_of_button",LISTENER);
```

Listener may be outside class or anonymous class like

```
.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            alertDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
```

Comment: These methods are on `AlterDialog.Builder`, not on `AltertDialog` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Good post by Tony Stark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13268371/1114170) and you can beautify your dialog by adding an icon .. Make sure you have the picture in your drawable folder.

```
 builder.setTitle("Message Sent!").setCancelable(false).setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                            {public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {dialog.cancel();}});
                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.send);//call your image for your icon here
                            alert.show();
```

Example
[image]