# android - set ID to the view programmatically

Tags: android, view, programmatically-created

I'm adding **Buttons** programmatically and the number of **Buttons** depends on some conditions. To add rules for **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams** that **Buttons** be aligned to the top of each other I need to set their *IDs*. All the answers from 2-3 years ago say that *setId(int)* is okay (e.g. *setId(1)*) but now it's forbidden (**UPD**. it's not ok only with int literals. With int variables everything is ok. Wonder why). How to do it nowadays?

Comment: Who says it is forbidden?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari it was underlined with red, and the method itself has an annotation IdRes

Comment: @ShadabAnsari and when I did "setId(i)" in loop it threw NullPointerException for the previous Button though I checked the "previous" id starting with the second.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)) it's not forbidden or deprecated. Here is the best way of using it.

1. Create `res/values/ids.xml` and define

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
           <item type="id" name="button1" />
           <item type="id" name="button2" />
   </resources>
   ```
2. once you have that, you can than use `setId`

   ```
   button1.setId(R.id.button1);
   button2.setId(R.id.button2);
   ```

Comment: when I tried "setId(1)" it was underlined with red. Thank you for your answer, gonna check it

Comment: Yes, it's because the function definition is `public void setId(@IdRes int id)` which forces you to pass an ID resource. Glad it helped.

Comment: It's not NPE anymore. But I could't solve my main problem - they keep overlapping each other though I wrote "lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,buttons[i-1].getId());" and then set it to buttons...

Comment: It's a different issue. You need to add another rule LeftOf or RightOf to the buttons. There is a solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700273/relativelayout-add-rule-relativelayout-left-of-not-working

Comment: Solved it! Many thanks! Just replaced "ALIGN_TOP" with "BELOW". And one more question (I know it's another topic too but maybe I be lucky): how to place programmatically-created RL at the bottom but outside the screen? ("rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM)" didn't help, it's placed top-left)

Comment: It depends on the parent layout of the RL.  ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM is for the items inside the new RL, so that won't work. What is your parent layout ?

Comment: RL. Maybe something happens with addContentView?

Comment: Ok, but...is it ok in comments?

Comment: Maybe you create another question. I'll try to answer there :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106669/discussion-between-justin-mcguire-and-arsent).

Answer (score 10):

Since you said you can have any number of buttons then you can set id for each button using -

```
button.setId(View.generateViewId()); //Works for API 17 and above
```

If `minSdk` is below 17, then you can use -

```
 button.setId(counter++); //Each time counter will be increment giving a unique id
```

Comment: only with API 17+. My sdkMin is 15

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: So strange... it's not ok using int literals (underlines red) but works with int variables