# Cannot create text input in a dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout

im new to android programming. I'm trying to make a dialog popup with a text input when a button a pressed. When i click the button, the app crashes. Any help please?

```
enterLP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog();
            ToggleButton youToggled = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
            ToggleButton oppToggled = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
            TextView yourLP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            TextView oppLP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            int lifePoints;
            if (youToggled.isChecked()){
                lifePoints = Integer.parseInt(yourLP.getText().toString()) - Integer.parseInt(reduceLP);
                yourLP.setText(Integer.toString(lifePoints));
            }
            if (oppToggled.isChecked()){
                lifePoints = Integer.parseInt(oppLP.getText().toString()) - Integer.parseInt(reduceLP);
                oppLP.setText(Integer.toString(lifePoints));
            }
        }

    });     


 public void showDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  

    alert.setTitle("Subtract Life Points:");  

    final EditText input = new EditText(this); 
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    alert.setView(input);  

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {  
        reduceLP = input.getText().toString();
      }  
    });  

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {  
          dialog.cancel();
      }  
    });  

    alert.show();  
}
```

LogCat Error:

```
05-12 01:59:30.002: D/dalvikvm(996): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 8% free 2458K/2656K, paused 82ms, total 87ms
05-12 01:59:30.011: I/dalvikvm-heap(996): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.157MB for 650176-byte allocation
05-12 01:59:30.102: D/dalvikvm(996): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 7% free 3090K/3292K, paused 82ms, total 83ms
05-12 01:59:30.212: D/dalvikvm(996): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 3090K/3292K, paused 13ms+9ms, total 111ms
05-12 01:59:30.723: D/dalvikvm(996): GC_CONCURRENT freed 646K, 22% free 2849K/3640K, paused 18ms+23ms, total 182ms
05-12 01:59:31.272: D/gralloc_goldfish(996): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-12 01:59:47.924: D/dalvikvm(996): GC_CONCURRENT freed 47K, 11% free 3251K/3640K, paused 75ms+108ms, total 305ms
05-12 01:59:48.021: D/AndroidRuntime(996): Shutting down VM
05-12 01:59:48.021: W/dalvikvm(996): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.aksynial.ygolpcalc.MainActivity$11.onClick(MainActivity.java:232)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-12 01:59:48.062: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 02:04:48.231: I/Process(996): Sending signal. PID: 996 SIG: 9
```

Hello, im new to android programming. I'm trying to make a dialog popup with a text input when a button a pressed. When i click the button, the app crashes. Any help please?

Comment: Please check this link. It might help..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968170/android-prompt-users-input-using-a-dialog

Answer (score 1):

Before you use the `parseInt` function, you don't check if the variable provided is empty or not.

You should modify the code to prevent this, the error you get just explains that in this case the value is empty and so the function cannot return an integer from it.

You should debug and check the value of these 3 variables: `reduceLP`, `yourLP.getText().toString()` and `opLP.getText().toString()`.

Comment: +1 Good answer. But the OP should note to not only check for empty value but to make sure that it is an `int` in case a user puts in something like a letter, space, special character, etc...

Answer (score 1):

These two lines -

```
lifePoints = Integer.parseInt(yourLP.getText().toString()) - Integer.parseInt(reduceLP);
                yourLP.setText(Integer.toString(lifePoints));

lifePoints = Integer.parseInt(oppLP.getText().toString()) - Integer.parseInt(reduceLP);
                oppLP.setText(Integer.toString(lifePoints));
```

changes to -

```
if(yourLP.getText().toString().matches("\\d+") || reduceLP..matches("\\d+") )
{
lifePoints = Integer.parseInt(yourLP.getText().toString()) - Integer.parseInt(reduceLP);
                    yourLP.setText(Integer.toString(lifePoints));
}

if(yourLP.getText().toString().matches("\\d+") || reduceLP..matches("\\d+"))
{
lifePoints = Integer.parseInt(oppLP.getText().toString()) - Integer.parseInt(reduceLP);
                    yourLP.setText(Integer.toString(lifePoints));
}
```

Just check whether `yourLP`, `oppLP` and `reduceLP` contain numbers.

Answer (score 0):

From catlog its clear that you are parsing non-integer value, so Numberformat exception

With all respect to @codeMagic cooment, here is how you can check

```
public boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    int ascii = 0;
    boolean isNumeric = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        ascii = (int) str.charAt(i);
        if ((ascii >= 48 && ascii <= 57)) {
            isNumeric = true;
            if (isNumeric) {
                return isNumeric;
            }
        }
    }
    return isNumeric;
}
```

Now, you can check

```
if(isNumeric(yourLP.getText().toString())){
lifePoints = Integer.parseInt(yourLP.getText().toString())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be doing these two things to simplyfy your code and avoid exceptions

1. parseInt on empty string causing the exception so check for emptiness as a guy said in the above answer.
2. Always use a LayoutInflator to create a custom view for dialog so

AlertDialog.Builder save_dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

```
save_dialog.setTitle(R.id.input_dialog_title);

LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

save_dialog.setTitle("Save your file");

View custom=inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_input_dialog, null);
    file_save_name=(EditText)custom.findViewById(R.id.input_file_name);
    save_dialog.setView(custom);
    save_dialog.setCancelable(true);
    save_as_ringtone=save_dialog.create();
    save_as_ringtone.show();
```

hope it helps you