# EditText dialog input always null (Android)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialog

The following code runs in the onClick method for a button and brings up a dialog box. I can enter text and press ok but my String filename, as shown in the Log.d, is always null. I do not understand why.

How do I get the text inputted in the dialog box to save?

My code runs in an activity(no fragment) and String filename and EditText input are both class member variables.

```
  // Get filename from user
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Enter filename");

    // EditText to get user input
    this.input = new EditText(this);
    dialog.setView(input);

    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            filename = input.getText().toString();
        }
    });

    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // cancelled
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Filename is : " + filename);
```

I based the code on [android prompt user's input using a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968170/android-prompt-users-input-using-a-dialog) but my issue is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try to Log the string before you actually input data into it.
try to put the log inside the positive onClick and I think you will see that it does save.

like so:

```
// Get filename from user
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialog.setTitle("Enter filename");

// EditText to get user input
this.input = new EditText(this);
dialog.setView(input);

dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        filename = input.getText().toString();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Filename is : " + filename);
    }
});

dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // cancelled
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

Comment: This works (shows what I inputted) but why does it not save to the member variable? I can't call this keyword on filename from within the onClick but I don't have another variable with that name.

Comment: it does save, but you can't use it in the same function where you called dialog.show(); because it will execute before the user will click on the OK in the dialog. what you need to do to use the filename is to put all the code inside the onClick function, or call another function from the onClick. 

(or if i didn't understand correctly please elaborate).

Comment: This works. I put the rest of the code in a private method and passed in the filename. I can see it was blocking something as I managed to get the second log statement (using the member variable) to run after I called the dialog box a second time. I don't fully understand the logic of why I need to move it though. I suppose a new method makes the code run in the parent class or activity and not inside the DialogInterface.OnClickListener() interface but still I thought my first way made sense.

Comment: in your original method the code for saving the input into the Filename variable was inside an inner class called OnClickListener. it would execute only after the user would click the button for OK.

The Log.d(...) command was written right after the dialog.show() command so it would execute right after a fraction of a second after the dialog was shown (before the user would get a chance to input anything and click ok.

(I hope I make sense)

Comment: I get it. The program kept going but the onClick callback hadn't happened yet. I seemed to have forgotten how callbacks work lol. Thanks.